# Two ways of creating subclass that are practically the same?

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm new to Java. I created a super class and a sub-class that extends from it:

```
class Car {
    private String name;
    private int wheels;

    public Car(String name, int wheels) {
        this.name = name;
        this.wheels = wheels;
    }
}

class Ford extends Car {
    public Ford(String name, int wheels) {
        super(name, wheels);
    }

}
```

And then in the main method I can create an instance of the super class and of the sub-class:

```
  Car car = new Car("car", 4);

   Ford ford = new Ford("ford", 6);

   Car ford2 = new Ford("ford", 6);
```

I just wanted to ask if there is any difference in creating the instance with Ford in the beginning, or Car in the beginning of the sentence? As you can see ford and ford2 are created differently. Please note that I know that ford and ford2 are not the same since they are reference variables with different pointers. I'm only wondering about the syntax with which they are created.
Thanks

EDIT:

I foud out the difference but don't understnand the logic behind it.

- In case you have a method in Car class, you can call it from both ford and ford2
- In case you have a method with the same name in Car and Ford classes, you can call it from both ford and ford2, and it will call the method in the sub-class
- In case you have a method only in Ford class, you CANNOT call it from ford2 - you will get an error.

I don't really understand why, ford2 is still an instance of Ford

Comment: What may be confusing you is the fact that you're using Car and Ford.... Having ford extend car implies that every ford is a car, which is not true (Ford would make more sense as a `make` field in the car class).... A better way to start would be to use Animal and Dog... and have Dog extend Animal

Comment: @RobOhRob Devil's advocate: Inheritance is a mechanism whose purpose is not necessarily to reflect real life. If it is useful and readable for the system in question to subvert reality and have `Ford extends Car`, then it definitely should.

Comment: I disagree, because this example could to be very confusing for beginners... because one could logically argue that Car could/should extend Ford

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't like any of these answers so far. They are making something simple sound complex.

A variable is just a holder for a reference.

As you can see from your examples, the type of the variable does not have to match the exact type of the reference it holds. The variable just has to be *equal to or more general* (or, if you prefer, *equal to or less specific*) than its reference. `Car` is more general than `Ford`, so that assignment is okay.

Every reference can be held by an `Object` variable, since that is the *most general* type which exists in Java.

```
Object foo = new Car(1, 6);
Object bar = "hello world";
```

Now, the difficulty with these variables is that we can only call the methods from the `Object` class. By declaring the variable as `Object`, when I try to access the contents then I can only use methods from `Object` no matter what's really stored in there.

There are a couple of methods in `Object` (like `toString`) so this may be okay, but in most cases assigning to `Object` is not very useful.

So, the more specific we are with our variables, the more functionality we potentially get access to.

When you say

```
Car car = new Ford("ford", 6);
```

there might be some Ford-specific functionality which we cannot access when referring to it from this variable. We can always get around that later by casting the instance but you should avoid doing so unless absolutely necessary.

However, the more general we are, the more flexible our code becomes. If a method only takes Ford cars as a parameter, that is quite restrictive. If it can take any car as a parameter, it is more flexible.

In general, when choosing the correct type for the variable, you can mentally start off with the most general type that you can, and then keep making it more specific until it fits your use case.

For example, if you can then prefer `Iterable` over a `Collection`, prefer `Collection` over a `List`, and prefer `List` over an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Definitely the best answer so far

Answer (score 1):

```
   Ford ford = new Ford("ford", 6);

   Car ford2 = new Ford("ford", 6);
```

Both object variable are referring Ford class object. but type of object variable are different. like ford is type of ford but ford2 is type of car.

Its called generalize object creation. generalize object reference creation is always suggest as you can change there object reference type by assigning different kind of subclass inheriting same super class.

Apart from this below mention difference is also a case which is useful.

```
Car car = new Car("car", 4);
```

This car object can only access Car class methods.

```
Ford ford = new Ford("ford", 6);
```

This object can access all methods of both class. But suppose you have 1 method like below in both class

```
   public static void a(){
        system.out.println("static method");
   }
```

if ford object call method a(). it will run method present in subclass. because ford variable is type of Ford subclass.

```
 Car ford2 = new Ford("ford", 6);
```

This object can access all methods of both class. But suppose you have 1 method like below in both class

```
   public static void a(){
        system.out.println("static method");
   }
```

if ford object call method a(). it will run method present in superclass. because ford2 variable is type of Ford superclass.

Comment: Please add the info that the example is about ```static``` methods, that doens't needs instances to be called, and also is not inhrited, so from child-class you can't call ```super.a()```

Comment: I cannot replicate what you're suggesting (that's why I asked this question in the first place). I created a method with the same name in both the super class and sub class. When I call it with ford.runMethod() and ford2.runMethod(), it goes to the method in the subclass for both of them. When there is a method only in the super class, for both ford and ford2 it will go to the superclass. So I still cannot find the difference
Thanks

Comment: Oh yeah I'm doing methods that are non-static, thanks for the clarification

Comment: create static method a in both class. change print statement like in super class syso and in sub class syso. then call same method from both object.

Comment: apart from that create 2 sub class inheriting same super class. then try to change object reference in both of your object created by assigning new sub class.

Comment: `generalize object variable creation is always suggest as you can change there object type`...  I find this very misleading... You aren't changing the objects type, you are changing the reference to the object.. A novice will read this and believe that the Ford object is actually becoming a Car object

Comment: @RobOhRob Thanks a lot rob. modified answer. I just started to write answer and working on writing effective and simple explanatory answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can call any `Ford` method on `ford`.

You can call any `Car` method on `ford2`.

Comment: But from my testings I see that I can call any Ford and Car method from both ford and ford2

Comment: That shouldn’t be possible – do you even have any `Ford`-specific methods? Your example code doesn’t.

Comment: Hey Michael, please see the edit that I made in the question, about the different scenarios, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Technically they are not same - `==` will give `false` - but they hold the same data (*not same* means modifying one will not affect the another) and they are the same type. But, you can only call `ford2`'s methods that are only defined in the `Ford` class (if there were any) by casting it to `Ford` (in this state, on `ford2` you can only call `Car`'s methods).

Answer (score 0):

> I just wanted to ask if there is any difference between the instance
>   ford and ford2? Or are they exactly the same?

The best answer is: **it depends**.

It depends on what, exactly, you mean by "the same."

In Java, the `new` operator is required to create a new object.  Therefore, the two assignments will assign newly created objects to the variables `ford` and `ford2`.  These objects will have different references and, therefore, different identities in the JVM.  As a result, the following will evaluate to `false`:

```
boolean b = (ford == ford2);
```

The two objects, however, can be said to have the same attributes as their instance fields contain the same values.  As it stands, this expression would also evaluate to `false`:

```
boolean b = (ford.equals(ford2));
```

because the default `equals()` method inherited from `Object` by both the types of the assigned variables (i.e., `Car` and `Ford`) performs the same reference comparison as was evaluated in the previous statement.  If the `equals()` method in the `Ford` class was overridden to perform a *value comparison* (instead of the default reference comparison) as follows:

```
@Override boolean equals(Object ob) {
    if (!(ob instanceof Ford)) return false;
    Ford f = (Ford) ob;
    return this.name.equals(f.name) && this.wheels == f.wheels;
}
```

then the following expression would evaluate to `true`:

```
boolean b = ford.equals(ford2);
```

TL;DR: the objects referenced by the variables `ford` and `ford2` have the same type (i.e. they are both `Ford`s), the same attributes, but different identities.  If a value comparison is defined for the class `Ford` as shown, then they would have the same values, otherwise they would not.

Comment: Thanks Scott, indeed I had to mention that by "the same" I acknowledge that they are reference types with different pointers and I only wonder if their properties are the same. Of course the reference variables discussion is irrelevant since if I created ford and ford2 with writing Car in the beginning, they would also not be "the same".
So your answer is that they share the exact same properties, and it doesn't matter if you create the instance with Car or Ford in the beginning of the sentence?
Thanks

Comment: *"So your answer is that they share the exact same properties, and it doesn't matter if you create the instance with Car or Ford in the beginning of the sentence?"* ... as the developer of the class, it is your responsibility to define the semantics for exactly what *"the same"* means.  You are free to define these semantics for `equals()` comparisons (the `==` operator, however, will always perform an identity comparison on reference types).  The type of the object variable i.e. `Car` or `Ford` does not impact upon the `equals()` semantics that are defined for the referred instance.